# No errors but doesnt write to database

Tags: php

thanks for taking the time to look at this.

No errors pop up, but nothing writes to the database.

Can someone help me out with what im doing wrong?

```
<?php
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','<USER>','<PASSWORD>');
mysql_select_db("rebeler_comment");

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cdb` ('',subject', 'comment' VALUES    ('',$subject','$comment')");


echo "Data successfully written to DB";
}

else{
echo "Sorry, there was a problem.";

}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: BTW, you're open to SQL injections. And you should use backticks for column names.

Comment: Use `mysql_error()`. It would tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Your MySQL syntax looks very awful...

Comment: 1. What @MarcelKorpel said.
2. Are you getting anything printed on the screen? Is "Data successfully written to DB" being written?

Comment: You forgot a closing `)` in `('',subject', 'comment'` and a `'`. Change to `('', 'subject', 'comment')`

Comment: @Fred-ii- And many more…

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Yes I just noticed.

Comment: @brian yes it does show data successfully written

Comment: Of course it shows that, as there's no error catching in your code.

Comment: @wumm, ty lol, I have little idea about what im doing in php, still learning, but need this up asap for a website I built for my team at work

Comment: Don't put this code live, or you will be hacked!

Comment: Also this `('',$subject','$comment')` change to `('','$subject','$comment')` yet you should use prepared statements, ***urgently.***

Comment: If you only have 2 columns to update, then all you need to do is use `('subject', 'comment') VALUES ('$subject','$comment')` if you have 3, then you will need to adjust accordingly. And wrap the first (2) in backticks, SO won't let me show them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

> ```
> $subject = mysql_real_escape_string($subject);
> $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
> $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cdb` (`subject`, `comment`) VALUES ('$subject','$comment')");
> ```

For checking error `check mysql_errno()` (is not 0 than error), `mysql_error()` contains error message

Comment: You can't surround column names with apostrophes (well, at least, you shouldn't). Use backticks instead (or nothing if they're not reserved words).

Comment: @CreatoR, ur awesome, thanks...at everyone else, thank you for posting, I love this place, I will work on getting this secured and all as well, and I will get better at php I promise wumm and marc, lol thanks guys/gals for the help

Comment: @MosesBolton There's usually a ***"happy ending"***, and this one was one of them, cheers.

Answer (score 7):

Of course there's no errors. You don't check for any, so you've missed the glaring syntax error in your insert query:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cdb` ('',subject', 'comment' VALUES    ('',$subject','$comment')");
                                         ^^---invalid field
                                            ^---unbalanced quote
                                                               ^---missing )
```

You can **NOT** quote field names with `'` quotes. That turns them into strings, not field names.

Your code should at absolute bare minimum have the following structure:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In short, your SQL is a disaster.

Comment: Plus a missing `)` before `VALUES`

Comment: And without that invalid field the number of values doesn't match the number of fields.

Comment: For columns: don't use a quote `'` but a backtick `\``

Comment: that's not an apostrophe, it's a backtick.

Comment: hey fred and marc ty, the missing ) is when I put it on this site, it is actually there in the code, I did add the '  to the begin of subject, still nothing, and again as is said before, I understand my SQl is horrible, but I am trying to learn so bare with me if you can

Comment: @MosesBolton No problemo. Yet you would be better off using the [PDO version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19793124/1415724)

Answer (score 3):

PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', '<USER>', '<PASSWORD>');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `cdb` (`subject`, `comment`) VALUES (:subject, :$comment)');
$stmt->execute(array(':comment' => $comment, ':subject' => $subject));
```

These extensions have built-in functions for creating prepared queries which let you use quotes and apostrophes without any problems. It is way better than using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension.